# Clean DNS server in JVM

Tags: java, dns, jvm

After my first post dealing with DNS,which is still not resolved: [JVM and OS DNS Caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17362758/jvm-and-os-dns-caching)
,i am facing a new problem.

First here is my use case: i want to check if my private DNS is alive. If not i want to use a general DNS (e.g 8.8.8.8).

My private DNS (a bind9 on ubuntu with 192.168.1.188) as a specific record: test.testdnd.fr -> 192.168.1.100

So i thought i could do this:

```
if(InetAddress.getByAddress(my_dns_ip_in_byte).isReachable()){
    System.setProperty("sun.net.spi.nameservice.provider.1", "dns,sun");
    System.setProperty("sun.net.spi.nameservice.nameservers", 192.168.1.188);
}else{
    System.setProperty("sun.net.spi.nameservice.provider.1", "dns,sun");
    System.setProperty("sun.net.spi.nameservice.nameservers", "8.8.8.8");
}
 InetAddress.getHostByAddress(test.testdnd.fr) -> unknow host exception
```

But if i only Do:

```
System.setProperty("sun.net.spi.nameservice.provider.1", "dns,sun");
System.setProperty("sun.net.spi.nameservice.nameservers", 192.168.1.188);
InetAddress.getHostByAddress(test.testdnd.fr) -> 192.168.1.100
```

So as soon as i called an InetAddress method before setting system.property, it seems that the system.property has no effect. Maybe because the JVM load the system DNS values when a InetAddress method is called even if it dont use DNS resolution.

Is that a standard behavior in the JVM or am i loosing something?

Any help is welcome,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting DNS property not having any effect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11957221/setting-dns-property-not-having-any-effect)

Comment: Its not really a duplicate, i want to use a private DNS server.

Comment: Are you sure `InetAddress.getByAddress(my_dns_ip_in_byte).isReachable()` is returning true? (if you haven't checked already you should add some debugging output to the if block to see)

Comment: Yup InetAddress.getByAddress(my_dns_ip_in_byte).isReachable() is returning true, and if i put a log in both brace-block,i see it doesn't go by the "else" block.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that the nameservice providers are loaded only once in `InetAddress` and cached for further use. The loading happens in the static initializer of the class `InetAddress`. So once `InetAddress` is initialized, setting or changing the `sun.net.spi.nameservice.provider` properties will have no more effect.

Answer (score 0):

The JVM only uses the DNS provider you set on lookups that fail using the system's default. You can see this in the documentation (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/net/properties.html), relevant excerpts:

> By default, Java will use the system configured name lookup
> mechanism
>
> You can specify a comma separated list of IP addresses that point to the DNS servers you want to use
>
> In JDK 7, providers are chained, which means that if a
> lookup on a provider fails, the next provider in the list is consulted
> to resolve the name.

Comment: Yeah, but in my case i try to resolved a private record (not present in public DNS). So normally the JVM should try to use the next provider (my private DNS) but i doesn't if i called a network method before setting properties